# Let a ∈ Z and suppose that the congruence $x ^2 ≡ a \mod p$ can be solved for all primes p except possibly finitely many, then a is square .

Tags: number-theory

Let a ∈ Z and suppose that the congruence
$x ^ 2 ≡ a \mod p$ can be solved (in x ∈ Z) for all primes p except possibly finitely many, then a
is a square in Z (i.e. a = b
2
for some b ∈ Z).

I tried solving the contrapositive and look at two cases:

$a = 2$ and $a \neq 2$.

For the first case i have proven that there are infinitly many primes that have a negative legendre symbol. So that has been proven.

I get stuck at the second case, i got a hint but i don't see how it can help me it says:

let a = $2^eq_1.....q_n$ and $L = \{l_1.....l_k\}$ be a set with primes that are odd and distinct of $q_i \forall i$. Let $s$ be a quadratic non-residue $\pmod{q_n}$. Argue that there exist a $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$b \equiv 1 \pmod{l_j} \space \forall l_j \in L$

$b \equiv 1 \pmod{q_i} \space i \in \{1,....,n-1\}$

$b \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$

$b \equiv s \pmod{q_n} \forall i$

and prove that $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = -1$. which also worked.

The next hint was proving that there exist a $p|b$ with $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ and $p \notin \{2,l_1,.....,l_k\}$

I think that such $b$ exist by the chinese remainder theorem, i dont see how the last statement is true and how it helps me to prove this equality.......

Kees